# LINQ: How to get the Max Id with a group by clause?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, group-by, max

I am looking for a way in LINQ to get a max Id record by using 'Group By' clause

Consider the following Sample data

```
  Table: ProcessAud

  ProcessSeq     ProjectSeq   ProjectValue    Active
      11              1           50000          Y
      12              1           10000          Y
      13              2           70000          Y 
      14              2           90000          Y
```

In which I want to get two records as a list such that is second and fourth
  records  (i.e) ProcessSeq 12 and 14. And I tried it like following

```
var ProcessAudList = ProcessAudService.FilterBy(x => x.Active == "Y"    
  ).GroupBy(x => x.ProjectSeq).Max().ToList();
```

It is not working properly, So how to do it in LINQ. Please anybody help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to pick top record from each group.

```
var ProcessAudList = ProcessAudService.Where(x => x.Active == "Y")
.GroupBy(x => x.ProjectSeq, (key,g)=>g.OrderByDescending(e=>e.ProjectValue).First());
```

Check [demo code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QRU53y)

Comment: Yeah, This is the right way, but only one thing we should change that is SingleOrDefault () instead of First (). Thank you for your response.

Comment: Indeed it should be `FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 6):

When you use GroupBy extension, method will return you IGrouping instance and you should query IGrouping instance like below;

```
var ProcessAudList = collection.Where(x => x.Active == "Y").GroupBy(x => x.ProjectSeq).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(a => a.ProcessSeq).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there, but `Max` is the wrong term to use.

Each `IGrouping` is an `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable`) sequence of its own, so you can use `OrderBy` and `First` clauses to get the answer you need:

```
var ProcessAudList = ProcessAudService
    .FilterBy(x => x.Active == "Y")
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProjectSeq)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProcessSeq).First())
    .ToList();
```

The `Select` clause will process each of the groups, order the groups descending by `ProcessSeq` and select the first one.  For the data you provided this will select the rows with `ProcessSeq` equal to 12 and 14.

Comment: Not working in ef core >3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: @TheZodchiy EF was not a part of this question directly. It's sad that they've decided to break a bunch of existing code, but that's their perogative. You can apparently shoe-horn in a `ROW_NUMBER()` implementation to do something similar, just on the server side. Also, it's been over 5 years. Let it go :)

Comment: This post really helped me. But I spent a lot of time looking for the problem, why everything works in your example, and errors in my code.

Comment: @TheZodchiy In native SQL I'd solve the problem with `ROW_NUMBER()`. EF Core 2 has a way to enable support for this, using `sqlOptions.AddRowNumberSupport()`. Check it out [here](https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore/_wiki/wikis/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.wiki/14/RowNumber-Support).

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get all max id in foreach

```
var res = from pa in ProcessAud
      group Cm by pa.ProjectSeq into Cm1
      select new
      {
           _max = Cm1.Max(x => x.ProcessSeq)
      };
foreach (var item in res)
{
    //item._max have biggest id in group
}
```